# Create small setup installer just for wizard, rest of files apart

Tags: installation, exe, inno-setup

i want to create my own installer for portable apps, games, etc.
Want to create an instalable app from a portable one... yes.

InnoSetup creates a unique EXE file with all app files inside it and i dont want to do that, it is so big and slow to create.

I just want to do an installable app like commercial games or apps, a little setup exe file with the installation wizard, and the all other files of the app/game located in the same directory to be copied to desired destination directory...

thks in advance,
Ima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To refer to the files in the installer's folder, use [`{src}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=src) and [`external` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=external).

To exclude the installer itself, use [`Check` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) to  compare [`CurrentFileName`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_currentfilename) to [`{srcexe}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=srcexe).

```
[Files]
Source: {src}\*; DestDir: {app}; Check: ExcludeSelf; Flags: external recursesubdirs
```

```pascal
[Code]

function ExcludeSelf: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (CompareText(CurrentFileName, ExpandConstant('{srcexe}')) <> 0);
end;
```