# Get the user download folder path using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How I get the user download folder path using Inno Setup?

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  if (FileExists(ExpandConstant('{%username%}\Downloads\file.txt'))) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Installation validated', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('Abort installation', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

This always came to end in `else` part.
There is constant for "user docs" and "user desktop" but not for "download". Can anyone please help me how I get user "download" folder path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for resolving environment variable is [`{%NAME}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=name), not `{%NAME%}`. Moreover the `USERNAME` environment variable is not a path, it's just a username. You want `USERPROFILE` instead:

```pascal
ExpandConstant('{%USERPROFILE}\Downloads\file.txt')
```

---

And hard-coding a path to `Downloads` folder seem like a bad idea to me. Who guarantees you that the file is there? I personally never download anything to the `Downloads` folder.

Aren't you actually looking for a file that is downloaded to the same folder, where your installer was downloaded to? Use `{src}` constant:

```pascal
ExpandConstant('{src}\file.txt')
```

See [Create small setup installer just for wizard, rest of files apart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73978577/850848)